# How to use "export-laravel-5-migrations _grt" plugin with mysql xampp on windows

Tags: python, laravel, windows, workbench

Xampp runs on my windows machine ( on d-disk)
Downloaded plugin: export-laravel-5-migrations
from

```
https://github.com/beckenrode/mysql-workbench-export-laravel-5-migrations/blob/master/export-laravel-5-migrations.py
```

After installing the plugin to Mysql-workbench, MYSQL workbench does not start anymore.

Only when I remove the plugin from /users/xxx/appdata/ropaming/mysql/workbench/modules
workbench can start up again.

Event viewer log on windows:

```
Faulting application name: MySQLWorkbench.exe, version: 8.0.25.0, time stamp: 0x6089097e
Faulting module name: python37.dll, version: 3.7.7150.1013, time stamp: 0x5f8050b5
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000013c7d4
Faulting process id: 0x2d04
Faulting application start time: 0x01d75d5af600ef93
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\MySQLWorkbench.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\python37.dll
Report Id: 3c354135-caed-40f3-9550-029022391b55
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I searched the web for a solution, but could not solve it.
Hope someone can help me analyze the problem.
Seems to have something to do with python37.dll

It is present in the reported path..

does anyone know how to solve this?

I would like to use the plugin to create a relational database setup for laravel.